# Virtual host on Apache2 for Mautic "This site can't be reached" on specified subdomain (but can be reached somewhere else)

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, ssl, apache2

I am configuring a brand new Mautic 5.0.3 instance on a Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) in AWS shared server with other 3 webs. Let's say (for security reasons) that its on aaaa.com.

I have configured a virtual host for Apache2 like I always do (and works) and for some reason I get the weirdest result I can't figure out why it doesn't work.

My mautic app should be reacheable on https://email.aaaa.com but instead I get the common unreacheable domain problem (DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN on Chrome, similar in any other navigator).

On the other hand, I don't know why I can reach my Mautic with https://emails.aaaa.com or https://emailz.aaaa.com or any similar variant. This shows a logical NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID error first, since SSL the certificate is for "email." but otherwise it works.

Extra information: on the main domain and with similar virtual host I have a WordPress installation (ie. https://aaaa.com) in case that might be the useful.

Is there any absurd reason I am overlooking that might explain and solve this?

Thanks a lot for you insight and help :D !

**This is my virtual host configuration in case it helps.** Any other comments/advice are welcome too, by the way (I am always ready to learn more :) ):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin             contacto@aaaa.com
    ServerName              email.aaaa.com

    DocumentRoot            /var/www/email.aaaa.com

    Redirect permanent      / https://email.aaaa.com/

    ErrorLog                ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/aaCom_mautic_error.log
    LogLevel                warn
    CustomLog               ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/aaCom_mautic_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    SSLEngine               on
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/ChavePublica_aaComEmail.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/apache2/ssl/ChavePrivada_aaComEmail.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/DigiCertCA_aaComEmail.ca-crt

    ServerAdmin             contacto@aaaa.com
    ServerName              email.aaaa.com

    DocumentRoot            /var/www/email.aaaa.com

    ErrorLog                ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/aaCom_mautic_error.log
    LogLevel                warn
    CustomLog               ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/aaCom_mautic_access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/email.aaaa.com>
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**Summarizing:**
Accesed https://email.aaaa.com/ > Expected my Mautic instance > Got a DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN .
Weird thing: it kinda works when I access https://emails.aaaa.com/

Comment: Check your DNS for the subdomains you are using.